# Android refresh ListView

Tags: android, listview, dataset, refresh

I know there are similar questions regarding this issue, but none of them worked for me.

I'm making an alarm clock app that has a `ListView` showing all alarms that are stored in the database. When the user long clicks one of the `ListView` items, it shows a dialogue confirming they really want to delete the selected alarm, after clicking the 'Yes' button, the alarm is deleted.

The problem is my `ListView` only refreshes after I start another activity and then go back to the one where the `ListView` is, I'd like to know what I need to do to refresh it as soon as the alarm is deleted.

PS.: I've already tried `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Here is my code:

```
UITools.adaptAlarmsListView(this, listView, R.layout.alarm_listview_item);
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                                               View view,
                                               final int position, long l)
                {
                    final boolean[] deletedFlag = {false}; // Tells if the alarm has been deleted
                    UITools.showDialogue(HomeActivity.this,
                            getString(R.string.delete),
                            getString(R.string.delete_question),
                            R.drawable.bin, getString(R.string.no),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(
                                        DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                                {
                                    // Do nothing
                                }
                            }, getString(R.string.yes),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(
                                        DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                                {
                                    AlarmDAO.delete(getBaseContext(),
                                            position + 1);
                                    UITools.showToast(getBaseContext(),
                                            getString(R.string.deleted),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    deletedFlag[0] = true;
                                }
                            });
                    if (deletedFlag[0])
                    {
                        listView.setAdapter(null);
                        UITools.adaptAlarmsListView(HomeActivity.this,
                                listView, R.layout.alarm_listview_item);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
    );
```

UITools.adaptAlarmsListView:

```
/**
 * Adapts the alarms ListView
 * @param context - Context
 * @param listView - ListView
 * @param listViewItemId - int
 */
public static void adaptAlarmsListView(Context context, ListView listView,
                                 int listViewItemId)
{
    Alarm[] alarms = AlarmDAO.getAlarms(context);
    AlarmAdapter adapter = new AlarmAdapter(context, listViewItemId, alarms);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: Just re-run the code that loads it in the first place.

Comment: @jzarsuelo, posted

Answer (score 0):

```
If your are using a fragment, just create an interface on that fragment 
and over the interface in the activity that hosts the fragment and
replace the present fragment with itself. or
create a method the re-initializes the listview, it adapter and the list.
if this is not clear enough, paste your code so i can check where the problem is.
```

Comment: No, I'm not using a fragment, I just edited my question, now with the code posted

Comment: in AlarmAdapter class, clear your ArrayList in Constructor before adding any new data. Then before listView.setAdapter(adapter);  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();